# Add one Day to one Calendar variable affects others

Tags: java, android, calendar

I simply do the following:

```
Calendar calDate = startEntryRoutine.getCalStartOfPeriod();
```

`startEntryRoutine` is a Thread which already finished and now just provides getter methods.
`.getCalStartOfPeriod()` returns a Calendar variable.

Now when I do;

```
Log.d(TAG, "createExampleList: " + startEntryRoutine.getCalStartOfPeriod().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"."+startEntryRoutine.getCalStartOfPeriod().get(Calendar.MONTH)+"."+startEntryRoutine.getCalStartOfPeriod().get(Calendar.YEAR));
calDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, +1);
Log.d(TAG, "createExampleList: " + calDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"."+calDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+"."+calDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
Log.d(TAG, "createExampleList: " + startEntryRoutine.getCalStartOfPeriod().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+"."+startEntryRoutine.getCalStartOfPeriod().get(Calendar.MONTH)+"."+startEntryRoutine.getCalStartOfPeriod().get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

The result is:

```
 createExampleList: 16.6.2019
 createExampleList: 17.6.2019
 createExampleList: 17.6.2019
```

But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because Java is pass by reference. you need to create a copy of calendar object to solve the problem.

```
Calendar cal2 = (Calendar) cal.clone();
```

and then do your changes.